# Can I use a custom tag inside an Django if block?

Tags: django, django-templates

Say I have this method:

```
def is_root_task(self, root=None):
    '''Returns true if the task is the root of a series of other tasks'''
    super_tasks = self.dependency_sub_task.all()
    if not root:
        return not super_tasks.exists()
    else:
        return not super_tasks.exclude(task_id__exact=root.id).exists()
```

And I register it like so:

```
from django import template
from gantt_charts.models import Task

register = template.Library()

register.tag('is_root_task', Task.is_root_task)
```

How do I call it inside an if block (or similar)? For instance say I want this to be in my page:

```
<ul>
{% for sub_task in task.sub_tasks %}
{% if is_root_task "sub_task" "task" %}
    <li >
        <p>{{sub_task.title}}</p>
        <p>{{sub_task.description}}</p>
    </li>
{% endif %}
{% empty %}
    <li> No Sub-tasks</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to pass the task variable (root) and sub_task variable (self) to is_root_task, and eval it inside the if block. Is that possible?

Comment: You'll need to make this a filter rather than a tag, then you can do `{% if sub_task|is_root_task:task %}`.

Comment: `with` template tag mays help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: I'll give these a go when back at with

Comment: @DanielRoseman that worked perfectly! Do you want to write an answer or shall I?

Comment: Go ahead and post the code you used, it's fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this with the help of [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)

Everything is the same except I've swapped out `tag` for `filter`. I'm not sure why filters work and tags don't but they do.

```
register.tag('is_root_task', Task.is_root_task)
```

And in the html I use:

```
{% if sub_task|is_root_task:task %}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Django 1.9 you can also do this in 2 steps by setting a variable from the tag output, then using the variable inside the `if`.

This is described towards the bottom of the Simple Tag documentation at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

In your case it would look like this:

```
{% is_root_task "sub_task" "task" as myflag %}
{% if myflag %}
    Do some stuff
{% endif %}
```

This way of doing things is good if you repeatedly use `myflag`, to avoid the overhead of repeatedly calling the tag.